# facebook og image share for highlight feature

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am sharing my website video page on Facebook. I have used a high resolution image in og meta tag.

**My Issue**

When I use the highlight feature for my post, facebook doesn't shows the big image like it is doing in the YouTube video sharing case. I am using following code:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="MysiteName"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="Post URL"/>    
<meta property="og:title" content="你好，喬，這是工作"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="video" />
<meta property="og:image" content="Image Url" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Enter Your Sub Headline Text Here"/>
<meta property="og:video" content="Video Url" /> 
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="2048" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="1024" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="AppID" />
```

Little preview to show, what i want to achieve. http://screencast.com/t/rxCbLySMEn
Please help to resolve the error.

Comment: So the image you want to show up as the first frame of the video is the image you have in og:image?

Comment: Did you use a URL to the **large** image in "Image Url"?

Comment: @hit1205 yes, i am using the same. Have you ever done this?

Comment: @Levi yes, og:image coming before all the other images on my webpage

Comment: i also mailed about this error to facebook. In response, they said, they will look onto this problem. I think, there is a some hidden values that are not disclosed in the api but mutually discussed with the youtube or vmeo.

Comment: @RaviKumar have you got any response over FB ticket ? if yes please share the solution/ticket. Thanks

Comment: @RaviKumar we are facing the same issue, have you any clue about this. any ticket logged to facebook support, or something.

Comment: @Gull I think YouTube and Other big companies has purchased some special services from Facebook. As per my research only the big websites like youtube, vimeo are able to do this. If you know any normal websites using the same feature then pls let me know, so i can start the research further.

Comment: Thanks, though my team reported a bug and FB accepted there is some issue https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/711926518872085/

Comment: Lets see what comes from FB side. Thanks

Comment: Hey guys, any progress related this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Which link are you passing in og:video?

YouTube does that with the use of the **og:video** tag.

- **og:image** for normal image
- **og:video** when video in highlight mode

The URL needs to be in this format:
`<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/k86xpd26M2g">`

Comment: i am already using meta video tag but not getting any success.

Comment: Have you used Facebook URL debugger to overwrite Facebook cache by loading the contents again? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: where you mentioned url should be in this format. <meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/k86xpd26M2g">. are you saying that url should not include any http get vars like ?abc=xyz. instead it should be abc.com/xyz then i will try this way also.